# Umbraco Page results filter reverts to default when navigating between pages XSLT

Tags: xslt, filter, pagination, umbraco

I've created an image gallery and am using the following filters to sort the results displayed on the page:

[image]

Which works great and filters as expected, until I navigate to another page within the pagination (.aspx?page=2) and the filter reverts to the default options. I need it to save the selected options and displayed the filtered results accordingly.

Here's a snippet of the XSLT I'm using, if needed I can post the entire XSLT:

```
    <xsl:variable name="FF_sortType" select="umbraco.library:RequestForm('sortType')" />
<xsl:variable name="FF_resultsPerPage" select="umbraco.library:RequestForm('resultsPerPage')" />        
<xsl:variable name="FF_details" select="umbraco.library:RequestForm('details')" />    
<xsl:variable name="FF_zoom" select="umbraco.library:RequestForm('zoom')" /> 

<!-- Filter the page results, Images per page, Most Recent/Alphabetical, Details On/Off, Zoom On/Off -->
<form action="#">
  <div class="imageGalleryAlbumFilter">
    <fieldset>
      <label>Images per page:</label>
      <select name="resultsPerPage" id="resultsPerPage" onchange="document.getElementById('BoostMasterForm').submit()" >
        <option value="8">
        <xsl:if test="$FF_resultsPerPage= '8'">
          <xsl:attribute name="selected">selected</xsl:attribute>
        </xsl:if>
        8 </option>
        <option value="20">
        <xsl:if test="$FF_resultsPerPage= '20'">
          <xsl:attribute name="selected">selected</xsl:attribute>
        </xsl:if>
        20 </option>
        <option value="40">
        <xsl:if test="$FF_resultsPerPage= '40'">
          <xsl:attribute name="selected">selected</xsl:attribute>
        </xsl:if>
        40 </option>
        <option value="60">
        <xsl:if test="$FF_resultsPerPage= '60'">
          <xsl:attribute name="selected">selected</xsl:attribute>
        </xsl:if>
        60 </option>
        <option value="80">
        <xsl:if test="$FF_resultsPerPage= '80'">
          <xsl:attribute name="selected">selected</xsl:attribute>
        </xsl:if>
        80 </option>
        <option value="100">
        <xsl:if test="$FF_resultsPerPage= '100'">
          <xsl:attribute name="selected">selected</xsl:attribute>
        </xsl:if>
        100 </option>
      </select>
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset>
      <label>Sort by:</label>
      <select name="sortType" id="sortType" onchange="document.getElementById('BoostMasterForm').submit()" >
        <option value="MostRecent">
        <xsl:if test="$FF_sortType= 'MostRecent'">
          <xsl:attribute name="selected">selected</xsl:attribute>
        </xsl:if>
        Most recent </option>
        <option value="Alphabetical">
        <xsl:if test="$FF_sortType= 'Alphabetical'">
          <xsl:attribute name="selected">selected</xsl:attribute>
        </xsl:if>
        Alphabetical </option>
      </select>
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset>
      <label>Details:</label>
      <select name="details" id="details" onchange="document.getElementById('BoostMasterForm').submit()" >
        <option value="On">
        <xsl:if test="$FF_details= 'On'">
          <xsl:attribute name="selected">selected</xsl:attribute>
        </xsl:if>
        On </option>
        <option value="Off">
        <xsl:if test="$FF_details= 'Off'">
          <xsl:attribute name="selected">selected</xsl:attribute>
        </xsl:if>
        Off </option>
      </select>
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset>
      <label>Zoom:</label>
      <select name="zoom" id="zoom" onchange="document.getElementById('BoostMasterForm').submit()" >
        <option value="On">
        <xsl:if test="$FF_zoom= 'On'">
          <xsl:attribute name="selected">selected</xsl:attribute>
        </xsl:if>
        On </option>
        <option value="Off">
        <xsl:if test="$FF_zoom= 'Off'">
          <xsl:attribute name="selected">selected</xsl:attribute>
        </xsl:if>
        Off </option>
      </select>
    </fieldset>
  </div>
</form>

<script type='text/javascript'>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#resultsPerPage").change(function() {
        $("#BoostMasterForm").attr("action", $(this).val());
        $("#BoostMasterForm").submit();
    });
    $("#sortType").change(function() {
        $("#BoostMasterForm").attr("action", $(this).val());
        $("#BoostMasterForm").submit();
    });
    $("#details").change(function() {
        $("#BoostMasterForm").attr("action", $(this).val());
        $("#BoostMasterForm").submit();
    });
    $("#zoom").change(function() {
        $("#BoostMasterForm").attr("action", $(this).val());
        $("#BoostMasterForm").submit();
    });
});​
</script>
```

If anyone can help it would be greatly appreciated.

Cheers, JV

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The umbraco.library static class has a bunch of helpers for managing session & other variables. As you are navigating using a querystring, the form is not submitted, and your controls inside XSLT do not have viewstate - the ability to retain their values between page submissions.

There are two ways around this:

1. Re-code your gallery (or your filter section) as an ASP.NET usercontrol, and enable viewstate on the controls;
2. When changing the form values, manually build a string in Javascript that contains the name and value of each control (or, save the values into a cookie with Javascript). Then, when paginating, either tack the Javascript string on the end of your querystring and retrieve the values using `umbraco.library:RequestQueryString("myparam")` in you XSLT, or retrieve the values from the cookies using `umbraco.library.RequestCookies("myparam")` to then determine which form options need making as "selected" when rendering your `<select>` options.

Comment: I'm not sure how to do either. But would prefer the second option. Also my page template has a form wrapping the content 'BoostMasterForm'. So I do not want a nested form. But removing the form from my filter XSL code, causes the filter to only work for a few changes. After a couple of changes it no longer filters. What should I do?

Comment: Do you have caching set on the macro? 

If you did, but didn't set macro properties, there is no way for umbraco to know that the output of the macro has changed, which is probably why your output becomes stale after "a couple of changes".

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways of doing this, though using a usercontrol is going to be slow and difficult to maintain. So I would stringly advice against using a usercontrol for this.

You don't need viewstate, nor do you need any call to the umbraco library.

You can simply use macro properties and use the macro property syntax to catch the query values. Umbraco has several means to solve this issue, though not many people are aware.

Please  note that this solution also solves any issues you might have with umbraco macro caching based on request variables.

In your XSLT you use a parameter to catch the macro value

```
<xslt:param name="numberofitems" select="/macro/numberofitems"/>
```

The macro property added should have an alias of "numberofitems"/number type.

Then in the macro call you on the template, you add the following line:

```
<umbraco:macro alias="mypagedmacro" numberofitems="[@numberofitems],[%numberofitems],10" />
```

Now call your pages with the request variable ?numberofitems=20

What happens here?

The first value will be coming from the request variable  "numberofitems" (20 in this case).

If that is not avialable, umbraco will look at a cookie to get the "numberofitems", in case you saved that in a cookie for later use.

And when that is not available, you have a default value of 10.

Add all your variable to the macro's and you can cache all different cases for this paged list.

For more info about macro syntax http://our.umbraco.org/wiki/reference/templates/umbracomacro-element/macro-parameters/advanced-macro-parameter-syntax